# HTML parser: convert html ISO-8859-1 encoded text to UTF-8

Tags: python, html, encoding, utf-8, html-parsing

I am trying to build an html mail parser in python 3.7 with Beautiful Soup.

The Content-Type in the email header is: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"

Here is some html code:

```
<div dir='3D"ltr"' id='3D"divRplyFwdMsg"'>
         <font color='3D"#000000"' face='=3D"Calibri,' sans-serif"="" style='3D"font-size:11pt"'>
          <b>
           Enviado:
          </b>
          jueves, 9 de mayo de 2019 11:16
          <br/>
          <b>
           Para:
          </b>
          DealReg
          <br/>
          <b>
           Asunto:
          </b>
          Integrated Quoting - Deal Registration ID 001009814954 pa=
ra Cliente client_name Revisi=F3n completa
         </font>
         <div>
         </div>
```

I need to encode the text correctly with UTF-8.

Where is "Integrated Quoting - Deal Registration ID 001009814954 pa=
    ra Cliente client_name Revisi=F3n completa" i expect "Integrated Quoting - Deal Registration ID 001009814954 para Cliente client_name Revisión completa"

I found some solutions but none of them works for me:

[1].

```
with codecs.open(html_path,"r", encoding = "utf-8") as html_file:
           text = html_file.read()
```

[2].

```
with io.open(html_path,"r", encoding = "utf-8") as html_file:
           text = html_file.read()
```

[3].

```
a = "Revisi=F3n"
b = a.encode("iso-8859-1").decode("utf-8")

>>>print(b)
"Revisi=F3n"
```

In [3] i also try to encode with ascii, latin-1, cp1252 and the result was the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the non-ascii characters have been encoded using the [quoted printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding (perhaps this html is from an email?).  The [quopri](https://docs.python.org/3/library/quopri.html) module can be used to encode them as `bytes`, which may then be decoded to `str`.

```
>>> import quopri
>>> s = 'Revisi=F3n'      
>>> quopri.decodestring(s)
b'Revisi\xf3n'   # bytes
>>> quopri.decodestring(s).decode('ISO-8859-1')
'Revisión'
```

The [quopri.decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/quopri.html#quopri.decode) function will decode an entire file.